# Lumen Virtual host in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu, virtualhost, virtual, lumen, host

I already implemented a virtual host for a laravel project and works without any problem and really had no problems on implementing all thing.

Now Im doing same for my lumen project but its not working:
`Hmm. We’re having trouble finding that site.`

This is how my test.local.conf looks:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port t>
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    #ServerName www.example.com

    ServerAdmin admin@test.com
    ServerAlias test.local
    ServerName test.local
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/test/public

    <Directory /var/www/html/test/public>
            Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
            Allow from all
    </Directory>
    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/test.local-error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/test.local-access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

I already restarted apache but it does not work. What I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In 3 questions I've made in stavkoverflow, in all 3 of them I answered to myself...

Anyway, no problem at all everyone who is struggling with this dont forget to add an entry to the machine hosts file as follow:

```
sudo nano /etc/hosts
```

add this line:

```
127.0.0.1       test.local
```

`ctrl+o` to save and `ctrl+x` to exit

Last step, just restart the apache:  `sudo service apache2 restart`

PS: If `127.0.0.1` is already taken you can set another ip like: `127.0.0.2`

Works like a charm!